# how do i disable mod_proxy from apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, tomcat

I have a `CentOS` running `Apache Tomcat`, I would like to replace `mod_proxy` by `mod_jk`,
I can see with `httpd -l` that these modules are loaded:

```
 mod_proxy_connect.c
 mod_proxy_ftp.c
 mod_proxy_http.c
 mod_proxy_scgi.c
 mod_proxy_ajp.c
 mod_proxy_balancer.c
```

How do I disable `mod_proxy` from Apache Tomcat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to disable mod_proxy by not loading it in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment out the following lines in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
```

and so on, for each module you want disabled.

and check the module is not being loaded elsewhere in /etc/httpd/conf.d/*